# How can I design a password system with 5000 three digit unique passwords?

Tags: probability

How can I design a 3 digit password system with 5000 unique passwords for a year 10 maths assignment

Comment: there are only 1000 numbers with 3 digits?

Comment: The cube root of 5000 is 17.09.. So you can't do it with 3 digits but you can do it with three charerters

Comment: Unless you live on a planet that uses base 18 or higher ...

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Since $10^3$ is only $1000$, you can’t do it with just *digits*: you’ll need to use more than ten different symbols.

- If you have $n$ different symbols in your alphabet, how many distinct $3$-character passwords can you make? There’s a pretty simple formula for this.
- Now use that formula to find the smallest value of $n$ that gives you $\ge5000$ passwords.

Comment: A better hint than I was going to give.

Answer (score 2):

Being a bit pedantic, it depends on what you mean exactly by a "digit". If you work with hexadecimal "digits" 0, 1, ... 9, A, B, ..., F, then you get $16^3= 4096$ possible passwords, so you need to devise a number system with slightly more than 16 digits.

Comment: 1_MiXedCAse,+2_Symbols